# Can an Ajax call be triggered by a text link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I completed a small tutorial-example using a drop down list that loads, with Ajax, some PHP pages.

My question is, can I use a text link instead of a drop down list? If so, how does the code change?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#category').change(function() {

    var val = $(this).val();
    $('#firstresult').empty().addClass('loading').load(val + '.php', function(){
      $('#firstresult').removeClass('loading') 
    });

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#yourLink').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();//so the link doesn't try to go somewhere
     var val = $(this).text();  //get value from the TEXT of your link

     $('#firstresult').empty().text('loading').addClass('loading');  //put 'loading' in your firstresult div and change the class to loading
     $('#firstresult').load(val + '.php', function(){  
      //load firstresult with what your php page returns
      $('#firstresult').removeClass('loading') 
    });

  });
});
```

Comment: Hi there. Can I have a value sent by the text link and display something in firstresult? Excuse me but I didn't fully understand how this will work.

Answer (score 0):

If #category is the id of your text link.

I entered return false to prevent the click event to bubble up and reload your page.

I haven't test it though...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#category').click(function() {

        var val = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#firstresult').empty().addClass('loading').load(val + '.php', function(){
          $('#firstresult').removeClass('loading') 
        });

        return false;

      });
    });
```

**EDIT**

```
<a id="category" href="my_val" title="">my link</a>
```

You can pass the value from the href attribute

Comment: How does it get the val? I mean where does it find it ?

Answer (score 0):

Do the same but with click function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#my_link').click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         var val=$(this).text();
         $('#firstresult').empty().addClass('loading').load(val + '.php', function(){
         $('#firstresult').removeClass('loading') 
         });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to give the text link an id, but probably leave the href off.

<a id='myTextLink'>Link</a>

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myTextLink').click(function() {

    var val = $(this).val();
    $('#firstresult').empty().addClass('loading').load(val + '.php', function(){
      $('#firstresult').removeClass('loading') 
    });

  });
});
```

Comment: The var val is useless right ? I mean you call one php file like example.php